# Select different file in file browse window during runtime

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Selenium web driver where i am to deal with File browse window. After trying different things finally i find a solution where i am using AutoIt.

Script is

```
@Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException, IOException 
    {
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='input-file-wrapper']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Process proc =Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\Upload.exe");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='go-btn']")).click();
        //driver.findElement(By.name("File name")).sendKeys("D:\\[Limetorrents.cc]_Daawat e Ishq          (2014) DvDScr x264 [DTRC] .torrent");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='cloud-free-btn']")).click();

        /*
        WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,50);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='vlc-   playlist']")));
    */
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    //  String i= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='seed-number']")).getText();
        boolean i1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='vlc-playlist']")).isDisplayed();
        System.out.println(i1);

        do
        {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            i1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='vlc-playlist']")).isDisplayed();
       }
           while(i1!=true);
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='trash']")).click();
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='confirm-to-remove']")).click();

    }
```

Script for AutoIt is as follow which has generate Upload.exe file, and that i have given in path name

```
WinWaitActive("File Upload")
Send("[kickass.to]desi.kattey.2014.1cd.dvdscr.rip.hindi.xvid.mp3.mafiaking.teamtnt.exclusive.torrent")
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Here it takes only single file every time i run this. How to take different files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoIt script has provision to pass parameters from command line. So when you are using `Runtime.exec("process")` to execute your autoit script, at that point of time pass the file name as argument and accept the command line argument in your script. Let me know if this helps.